# Eclipselink: OSGi bundles, inheritance and weaving

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink

I have three bundles. In first bundle I have persistence.xml. And I have two classes : A and B. A extends B. Class A is @Entity, Class B is @MappedSuperclass.Both classes are listed in persistence.xml. Packages of the 2'dn and 3'rd bundles are exported.

If class A and class B are in the same bundle - everything ok. However, when class A in the second bundle and class B is the the third bundle I get:

```
WARNING: EMFProxy invocation on method createEntityManager failed:  Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.classloader.CompositeClassLoader@20c0a64d
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [myPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.TransformerFactory.createClassDetails(TransformerFactory.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.TransformerFactory.addClassDetailsForMappedSuperClasses(TransformerFactory.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.TransformerFactory.buildClassDetailsAndModifyProject(TransformerFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.TransformerFactory.createTransformerAndModifyProject(TransformerFactory.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1972)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.ProviderWrapper.createEntityManagerFactory(ProviderWrapper.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.createEMF(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.syncGetEMFAndSetIfAbsent(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.invoke(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
```

When I set in persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
```

I don't get any exceptions, but all fields from class B are ignored. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Set EclipseLink logging to finest or all and check out the logs as EclipseLink is loading each class during deployment to see if all your classes are picked up.  It should then show any warnings or errors that might prevent the 'B' from being loaded.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your time. It didn't help but it gave a hint - I noticed that any classes from one of the bundle are ignored and finally found out the reason. See my answer.

Comment: @Chris By the way, is the any way make some maven bundle to read persistence.xml classes and add absent packages to manifest? Or other good solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the first bundle. It didn't import packages from bundle with class B as its code didn't know anything about class B. So I had to add in  manifest file of the first bundle osgi directive import package - class B package. The problem in EclipseLink is that it didn't throw any exceptions about class not found or something like this even with logging level All.